# Сравнения содержимого двух массивов, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, массивы

Есть 2 массива (знаю код плох, но дорабатываю тек. функционал)

```
 let util = [],
      cap = [];

    $(".util").each(function(i,item){
    len = $.trim($(item).parent().parent().find(".len").data("cost")).split('-'); 
   //изначально строка "55-65", поэтому обрезаю через split

    util.push(len); //Многомерный массив
    })

    $(".caps").each(function(i){
                        cap.push($(this).data('capacity'));
                })
```

Получаем на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать проверку вхождения массива в другой массив гибко.

Число `60` входит в диапазон `55-65` - вычеркиваем. 
35 не входит не в один массив- оставляем. 
 190 входит в 170-210 диапазон - вычеркиваем

Подскажите, как это можно вообще реализовать? То есть в итоге должно остаться то что не входит,в данном случае 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так отфильтруется второй массив по содержимому первого

```js
let intervals = [["55", "65"], ["170", "210"]];
let numbers = [60, 35, 190]

let result = numbers.filter(n => intervals.filter(i => n>i[0] && n<i[1]).length === 0)
console.log(result)
```

---

А вот так, наоборот, содержимое первого фильтруем по второму:

```js
let intervals = [["55", "65"], ["170", "210"]];
let numbers = [60, 35, 190]

let result = intervals.filter(i => numbers.filter(n => n>i[0] && n<i[1]).length === 0)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: объяснения нужны?

Comment: Все отлично, только все таки наоборот надо. Чтобы убирало с intervals, а не numbers. Не подскажешь, как это подправить?

Comment: @AndreyOsipov тоесть должен остаться пустой массив?